# Unable to change the Image Opacity by using Imagick

Tags: php, image, imagick

I want to change the opacity of images in php. I used Imagick and it is working fine for creating thumbnails, converting images etc, but not working for **SetImageOpacity** method.

My code is:

```
<?php
$image = 'a.png';
$im = new Imagick($image);
$im->pingImage($image);
$im->readImage( $image );
$im->setImageOpacity( 0.3 );
$im->writeImage( 'changed.png' );
?>
```

But it is not working. Can anyone please tell me the reason my code is not working? I searched for the code and every where i got the same code. So, what is the problem please help.......

Comment: What imagemagick version do you have?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagick-setimageopacity.php
This method is available if Imagick has been compiled against ImageMagick version 6.3.1 or newer.

So you will need recompile your imagemagic version to newer